# Infer subtype of T based on a condition function (t: T) => boolean that matches that condition

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get better type checking in redux saga. I have tried to get a more simple standalone example to show what I want. Based on a condition function `(t: T) => boolean`, I want to infer the subtype of T that matches that condition.

I'm not sure if this is possible in typescript. I thought maybe with the new assert functions, but I could not get that to work. Here is an example:

```js
type Actions =
  | {
      type: 'A';
      subType: 'A';
      payload: string;
    }
  | {
      type: 'A';
      subType: 'B';
      payload: number;
    }
  | {
      type: 'B';
      payload: number[];
    };

declare function takeEvery(
  condition: (action: Actions) => boolean,
  worker: (action: Actions) => void,
): void;

takeEvery(
  action => action.type === 'A' && action.subType === 'B',
  action => {
    const payload = action.payload;
    // payload should be inferred as number here
    console.log(payload * 2);
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to require some kind of manual type annotation to work.  The most straightforward interpretation of what you're looking for would be to make the `takeEvery` function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in `T`, the particular subtype of `Actions` that you're dealing with, and to make the `condtion()` function a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) function whose `boolean` return value acts as the type predicate `action is T`.  Like this:

```
declare function takeEvery<T extends Actions>(
    condition: (action: Actions) => action is T,
    worker: (action: T) => void,
): void;
```

Unfortunately, the compiler cannot look at a function of the form

```
(action: Actions) => action.type === 'A' && action.subType === 'B'
```

and *infer* what type guard it represents.  This is a [longstanding, open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069) and I don't know if it will ever be addressed.  The best you can do for now (as of TS3.7) is to manually annotate it yourself:

```
takeEvery(
    (action): action is Extract<Actions, { type: "A", subType: "B" }> =>
        action.type === 'A' && action.subType === 'B',
    action => {
        const payload = action.payload;
        console.log(payload * 2); // no error now
    },
);
```

That works exactly as you want; `payload * 2` is no longer an error.  But since you had to write out `Extract<Actions, { type: "A", subType: "B" }>` explicitly, I don't know if it buys you much over other ways of manually specifying types, such as this:

```
takeEvery<Extract<Actions, { type: "A", subType: "B" }>>(
    (action): action is any => action.type === 'A' && action.subType === 'B',
    action => {
        const payload = action.payload;
        console.log(payload * 2); // no error now
    },
);
```

Or even this with your existing typings:

```
oldTakeEvery(
    action => action.type === 'A' && action.subType === 'B',
    a => {
        const action = a as Extract<Actions, { type: "A", subType: "B" }>
        const payload = action.payload;
        console.log(payload * 2); // no error now
    },
);
```

Personally I think the generic version where the type guard function is manually annotated (the first answer above) is the least bad of those options, but unfortunately I don't know if I have anything great here.

Oh well, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYGcoF4CwAoKQqAHygG98iqpRIAuKAchkYG5LrD0BXAIwBVwEBszYdOYAIYgANskkATBumAAnRKgDm7AkQC+4kuUNVawpix2cufQfSYAhMbonS5ihqm4BbXhFVW+oakFC7UZiJOga6y8kpQXr7+ANoAutFQejr4ChBwMpKq0ABm3KgIKKg0kgDWEACiAG7+IAA8-FAQAB7AEKgKmPBIaOgAfAAUhnBoCojDqAzjkhVoDEOV6ACU2KNQy-NQiJj8ADSGAO7IqnWqi-uVDPzbWLuNyIgKZ3ibDG8f2XhgLUGs1VCBJmElitUD89tDDph6j1VPtWusRidyDQhAwAEQwXGYngCHFQXEOXGZXYvExEe5oAB0ZmwWCwFkYUAAZJy4fMGcS7NBWWzGE4vlR6VUXsYwlRphhgFApLFFNheZUGcr3AoMnKRsgZBAGXJNOMtXEoAAqKAAJk2rCgAHpHQlkJ1VKorq7zoY9F97fh8EC6k0Wq0kWpUeiMJiyNj7PjCVABaTyZS9KMJoYofNYZKEXtUCAdurGczheyuTzJfzbEIWSKxYZ89LQtYoPKVEq3Ba2TXzYpdUROwajSazT3Vda7Q7na73Z7VN7ff6AYG8Ll8oUSmV4QaFPxgaGwRC9f05g8oDnL9GtiXeMhR5JUOKiJdrv47tC1tC79K-p8+CwgBAL7oeIaguCzbwtKNblqylbcqWqC1iSkANo4jCvoQkglm21idoqLZ7HsiLIlGv6xvG5iJkSdYJhSVK0oQhHdiqChqv2k46sxHb6oaxrIKaA4cdO9pOi6qBuv4i7LmEfpAWueDrkAA)